# Using Javascript and tabs to change page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create some sort of script that will change the certain text when I go to a new tab. I am a noobie to Javascript and okayish with HTML and CSS.

Here is the link to my work so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/gbjwn08y/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:red;}
#Paris {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Oslo</h3>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'green')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Oslo</button>
<p>
This text right here
</p>
<script>
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see, I have the tabs working with the text. I need the "This text right here" to change depending on which tab is clicked.
I am also going to make a preset font using for "This text right here".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the "This text right here" supposed to change to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element for each text block you want to show, add a class to it that matches the `cityName` it's associated with, and when you click on a tab, show the text block that has the `cityName` in it's class and hide the rest.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:red;}
#Paris {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}
.text {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Oslo</h3>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'green')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Oslo</button>
<p class="Oslo text">
oslo
</p>
<p class="Paris text">
paris
</p>
<p class="Tokyo text">
tokyo
</p>
<p class="London text show">
london
</p>
<script>
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
    var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
     if (texts[i].classList.contains(cityName)) {
       texts[i].classList.add('show');
      } else {
       texts[i].classList.remove('show');
      }
    }

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was an If command to use but I just didn't know how to use it because I'm new to javascript. If I wanted to edit my text via <Style> how would I just put "London text show" {

Comment: @DenisG you're welcome. what do you mean edit your text via style?

Comment: I was wondering if I can format the "Tokyo text" this way:
<style>
"Tokyo text" {
        text-align: center;
        font: example;
}
</style>
If I were going to do it this way would I also need to include in an id= to the <p class="Tokyo Text">?

Comment: yeah just use `<style>.Tokyo { text-align: center; font example; }</span>`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this. Since you haven't mentioned what change you want your text to make, I just assume text in `<p>` to be any strings. You may add two more simple functions to approach this:

```
function changeText(newText) {
  let text = document.getElementById('text');
  text.innerHTML = newText;
};

function handleTabClick(cityName, elmnt, color, newText) {
  openCity(cityName, elmnt, color);
  changeText(newText);
}
```

In this case, each of your function will be in charge of only one thing, which might be better for debugging and future editing.

After this, take two more steps:

1. add `id="text"` to `<p>` element
2. change `onClick` handlers for your buttons to be `handleTabClick` and give corresponding arguments.

To see it works, click [here](https://jsbin.com/yahovoguqi/1/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the element you want to change, for example `<p id="test">`  and then add the following:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = cityName;
```

after:

```
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

This will replace the text with the city name.  Hopefully you can further customize to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:red;}
#Paris {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Oslo</h3>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'green')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Oslo</button>
<p id="city">
I need this text to change
</p>
<script>
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

 var s = document.getElementById("city");
            s.innerHTML =  cityName;
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```